# Parse the XML in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

```
<ROOT>
    <arn>arn001</arn>
    <arn>arn002</arn>
</ROOT>
```

Tried the following code though

```
SELECT
ARN.value('(//arn/text())[1]','VARCHAR(100)') AS arns --TAG
FROM
@xml.nodes('/ROOT')AS TEMPTABLE(ARN)
```

It returns only first value

Comment: What do you want it to return?

Answer (score 1):

Try this way :

```
declare @xml xml = '<ROOT>
        <arn>arn001</arn>
        <arn>arn002</arn>
    </ROOT>'

SELECT
X.value('.','VARCHAR(100)') AS arns 
FROM
@xml.nodes('/ROOT/arn')AS T(X)
```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb/5057)**